# va_list and va_arg

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I using va_list like this:

```
void foo(const char* firstArg, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, firstArg);
    for (const char* arg = firstArg; arg != NULL; arg = va_arg(arg, const char*)) {
         // do something with arg
    }

    va_end(args);
}
```

foo("123", "234", "345")

the first three arguments was passed to foo correctly, but where "345" is done,

```
 arg = va_arg(arg, const char*)
```

set some other freak value to **arg**.

so What's the problem. I using llvm3.0 as my compiler.

Comment: OK, i do it like this `foo("123", "234", "345", NULL)`. i will test if it work.

Comment: You should really be passing `(char*)NULL`, as `NULL` may be defined as a plain 0 and the compiler has no way to implicitly know it's a pointer value without a cast.  This is especially important if `sizeof(int) != sizeof(char *)` which is not that uncommon with 64-bit implementations.

Comment: Not true, actually.  In C11, §7.19 `<stddef.h>` states that _The macros are
`NULL`
which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant;_ so only a broken implementation can have NULL defined in a way that is not equivalent to a null pointer.  The wording in C99 in section §7.17 `<stddef.h>` is the same, and I believe C89 was essentially the same too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Hm you make an interesting point.  I was thinking back to http://c-faq.com/null/macro.html which is generally pretty reliable (albeit pedantic), but it's not really clear in their answer where it could be a plain 0.

Comment: `echo "#include <stddef.h>\nNULL" | gcc -E -x c -` => `((void *)0)` while `echo "#include <stddef.h>\nNULL" | gcc -E -x c++ -` => `__null`. gcc 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64.  See also http://c-faq.com/null/safermacs.html

Comment: @FatalError POSIX defines `NULL` to be exactly *"`0` cast to type `void *`"*.  Also, the Linux manual page says NULL should be cast, but POSIX doesn't say that, so I guess the Linux manual page is simply collecting tradition and should probably be fixed.  POSIX exec(3p): *"The list is terminated by a null pointer"*.

Answer (score 11):

C does not automatically put a `NULL` at the end of a `...` argument list. If you want to use `NULL` to detect the end of the arguments, you must pass it explicitly. Some functions (such as `printf`) use earlier parameters to decide when they have reached the end of the arguments.

(**Edit**: And actually if you want to put a `NULL` at the end, you need to cast it to the appropriate type so that it gets passed as the correct type of null pointer.)

Comment: Could you please provide extra info or link on how `printf()` figures out when it has reached the `end of the arguments`. Is the working of `printf()` exactly similar to the working of any other `function with a variable number of arguments`?

Comment: It counts the number of percent signs.

Comment: I'm just assuming that `printf()` uses 2 pointers of type `va_list()`. One to keep the track on the arguments & other for the `%`. Is that right?

Comment: You don't need a va_list to count percent signs in a string.

Answer (score 4):

I think the loop should be as follows:

```
for (const char* arg = firstArg; arg != NULL; arg = va_arg(args, const char*))
```

The change is `va_arg(args, const char*)` instead of `va_arg(arg/*<<==*/, const char*)`.