# libxml2 - xmlSchemaValidityErrorFunc - centos5 - libxml2-2.9.1 - gcc

Tags: c, xml, gcc, xsd, libxml2

Have been trying to write a custom error function for validating schema errors in libxml2.

Just want to know what is the last argument does libxml2 expect to send to this function.

```
static void logXSDValidationError(void * ctx, const char * firstArg, ...) {

    printf("In logXSDValidationError \n");

    va_list args;
    va_start (args, firstArg);
    const char* arg = firstArg;

    //while(arg != NULL) {      // Char arrays do not seem to end with NULL
        printf("In While \n");
        arg = va_arg(args, const char*);
        printf("[%s]", arg);
        printf("Out While \n");
    //}

    va_end(args);

    printf("Out logXSDValidationError \n");

    return;
}
```

Have had a look at this [va_list and va_arg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936249/va-list-and-va-arg). It does seem to suggest to pass in null as the last argument, but in this case i guess libxml2 will put in the last argument.